# $("#form1").validate is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function() { 
      $("#form1").validate({ 
        rules: { 
         budget: {
            required: true,
             minlength:3
        } ,
       duration: {
            required: true,
            digits:true
        }, 
         town: {
            required: true,
             minlength:2

        },

       content: {
            required: true,
            minlength:300 

        }
         }, 
        messages: { 


        } 
          }); 
        });
        -->
</script>
```

Two jquery files are included.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../common/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

are included. There is nothing wrong with the inclusion.

I got an error message

> $("#form1").validate is not a function
>   What's wrong?

Comment: I would have to assume the path to jquery.validate.js is wrong.

Comment: Do you have a <from id="form1" in your html? If it's ASP.NET and has runat=server in it too, then the name will have changed if you view the HTML source in your browser.

Comment: Yes,<form id="form1"> exists in my html.

Comment: Jquery.validate.js is not wrong.

Comment: Well, just for sanity's sake, link to it using a CDN, like you are with jQuery's script. Here: http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.5.5/jquery.validate.min.js

Comment: Waiting for more suggestions.

Comment: Hey steven, just tested your code without issue. What browser is throwing the error?

Comment: If you are using Firebug, you can click over to the "Net" tab and see the various resources (images, stylesheets, scripts) that your page has loaded, along with status code. Errors are highlighted in red. See if the "validate.js" is a 404 error or 200 OK (or 301). You can also expand the item to see what was really retrieved.

Comment: I "view page source" and clicked "validate.js", it  can be seen successfully.

Comment: This worked for me fine in IE.  Can you post your HTML?

Answer (score 34):

#### Put the jQuery script tag *before* the script tag for validation

I just encountered this extremely frustrating error and lost the better part of an hour to it, for lack of a workable answer online. I confirmed in Firebug that I was hitting the CDN for both jQuery and validation.

In the end, changing this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

was all I needed.

Comment: Try to solve this issue since last couple of days. Thanks. Works :)

Comment: Any jQuery extension or plugin has to be included after jQuery is, otherwise how is your script to extend it?

Comment: Mine was caused by that I loaded jQuery from local file system but jQuery-validate from CDN. After I changed to load both from local file system, it immediately works.

Answer (score 21):

I had this same issue.  It turned out that I was loading the jQuery JavaScript file more than once on the page.  This was due to included pages (or JSPs, in my case).  Once I removed the duplicate reference to the jQuery js file, this error went away.

Comment: Thank you sir -- only spent several hours on this.  If the libraries can't cope with multiple jQueries, then it would be nice if jQuery itself could throw an error when loaded more than once!

Comment: Yes ,This is the most common issue when we are referencing an element  twice for some callback.

Comment: I'm curious as to why my answer was down-voted, since it has proven helpful to most folks.

Comment: I had iframe elements in my webpage that were also including jquery.min.js file.

Comment: After wasting of almost 1 hour,here is the solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, and yes I had my jquery included first followed by the jquery validate script.  I had no idea what was wrong.  Turns out I was using a validate url that had moved.  I figured this out by doing the following:

1. Open firefox
2. Open firebug
3. Click the NET tab in firebug.  This will show you all the resources that get loaded.
4. Load your page.
5. Check the loaded resources and see if both your jquery & jquery.validate.js loaded.

In my situation I had a 403 Forbidden error when trying to obtain (http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js which is used in the example on http://rocketsquared.com/wiki/Plugins/Validation ).

Turns out the that link (http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js) had moved to http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js (Firebug told me this when I loaded the file locally as opposed to on my web server).

NOTE: I tried using microsoft's CDN link also but it failed when I tried to load the javascript file in the browser with the correct url, there was some odd issue going on with the CDN site.

Answer (score 2):

youll need to use the latest http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.5.5/jquery.validate.js in conjunction with one of the Microsoft's CDN for getting your validation file.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue; validated HTML & found I was missing a `name="email"` attribute from an `<input />`. Always validate the HTML to be **positive** your HTML is valid. After I added it, `validate()` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that jQuery is using the $ variable, and its not another javascript framework.

Check your doctype: Validate your html, sometimes browsers don't see stuff in quirks mode, or when they encouter malformed html.

Also ensure that jquery.validate.js file is correct.

You can download it below:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: How to ensure that jquery.validate.js file is correct? I think it is correct.

Comment: Aha I was having this issue and it was because jQuery wasn't using the $ variable. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 1):

Check if you use Proxy.

I've got this problem in Mozilla Firefox, I thought it's some issue related to the Firefox itself. Later I found out that I am using a proxy server. 
When I unchecked the proxy, everything got fine.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the browser first downloaded the validade script and then jQuery. If the validade script be downloaded before loading jQuery you'll get an error. You can see this using a tool like firebug.

Try this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function LoadValidade() {
        var a = false;
        try {
            var teste = $('*');
            if(teste == null)
                throw 1;
        } catch (e) { 
            a = true; 
        }

        if (a){ 
            setTimeout(LoadValidade, 300);
            return;
        }

        var validadeScript = document.createElement("script");
        validadeScript.src = "../common/jquery.validate.js";
        $('head')[0].appendChild(validadeScript);
    } 
    setTimeout(LoadValidade, 300);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

my solution to the problem:
in footer add `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

In my case i moved the validate part outside of the document ready function and it works fine for me. I hope it would work for u...

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   // paste validate function outside of the document ready function...
});

    $('#form1').validate({

        rules: {
            English_Name: { required: true, minlength: 3 },
            Arabic_Name: { required: true, minlength: 3 },
            latitude: { required: true, min: 16, max: 32, number: true },
            longitude: { required: true, min: 32, max: 52, number: true },
            EmployeeID: { required: true },
            PaymentTypeID: { required: true },
            BusinessTypeID: { required: true },
            SalesTypeID: { required: true },
            OutletLength: { required: true },
            OutletWidth: { required: true },
            CONTACT_PERSON: { required: true },
            MOBILE_NO: { required: true, minlength: 9, maxlength: 13, digits: true },
            TRADE_LIC_DATE: { dateValidation: true },
            CreditLimit: { min: 0, max: 2000000 },
            CreditPeriod: { min: 0, max: 365 },
            EMAIL_ADDRESS: { email: true },
            BusinessClassID: { required: true },
            CustomerClassificationID: { required: true },
            LicenseTypeID: { required: true }
        },
        message: {
            English_Name: {
                required: ''

            },
            ToDate: {
                required: ''

            }




        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/sfa/Verification/SaveDataInDatabase',
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '.5');
                },
                success: function (msg) {


                    $("#form1").trigger('reset');
                    $('.modal').modal('hide');
                    $('.submitBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
                    $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '');
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had a link I could look to see what the issue is but here are a couple questions and things to check:

- Is the ID for your form named "form" in the HTML?
- Check to see if messages are required, maybe there is some imbalance in parameters
- You should also add the 'type="text/javascript"' attributes where you are getting jQuery from Google

Also, if you're going to use the Google CDN for getting jQuery you may as well use Microsoft's CDN for getting your validation file. Any of these URLs will work:

- http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.5.5/jquery.validate.js
- http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.5.5/jquery.validate.min.js
- http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.5.5/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js

Comment: I have tried the URLs you provided, but the problem still can not be eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe silly, but check that you inline script is AFTER you include the script tags.

Comment: If you use Firbug: test to write $.fn.validate in the console and see if it's declared.

Are you using any other js-librarys in the same solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, jquery URL was valid, everything looked good and validation still worked. After a hard refresh CTL+F5 the error went away in Chrome.

Comment: This not explain the reson of the error. Please, can you be more concrete.