# Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined

Tags: jquery, validation

I have the following code:

```html
<div class="signup_form">
  <form action="#" method="post" id="registratie">
    <div class="row-fluid ">
      <div class="span12">
        <label for="volledige_naam">VOLLEDIGE NAAM</label>
        <input type="text" name="volledige_naam" tabindex="1" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span6">
        <label for="gebruikersnaam">GEBRUIKERSNAAM</label>
        <input type="text" name="gebruikersnaam" tabindex="2" />
      </div>
      <div class="span6">
        <label for="email">E-MAIL</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" tabindex="3" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span6">
        <label for="wachtwoord1">WACHTWOORD</label>
        <input type="password" name="wachtwoord1" tabindex="3" />
      </div>
      <div class="span6">
        <label for="wachtwoord2">HERHAAL WACHTWOORD</label>
        <input type="password" name="wachtwoord2" tabindex="4" />
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid bottompad">
      <div class="span2 ">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="span8">
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" value="Verzenden" name="submit" class="toppad button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>VERZENDEN&nbsp;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="span2">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

And the javascript is:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-JAW99MJVpJBGcbzEuXk4Az05s/XyDdBomFqNlM3ic+I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

<!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823998/jquery-validation-error-validate-is-not-a-function -->    

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#registratie").validate({
        rules: {
            volledige_naam: {
                required: true,
                rangelenght: [4, 20]
                // remote:"look.php"
            },
            gebruikersnaam: {
                required: true,
                rangelenght: [4, 20]
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            wachtwoord1: {
                required: true,
                rangelenght: [4.20]
            },
            wachtwoord2: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#wachtwoord1"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            gebruikersnaam: {
                required: "Please enter a username",
                minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 3 characters"
            },
            wachtwoord1: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            wachtwoord2: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
                equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined

in the console.

Any idea what goes wrong?

Comment: The markup is invalid. The closing `</div>` above `<div class="row-fluid bottompad">` has no corresponding opening `<div>`

Comment: Tnx  but I copied the code wrong, the closing </div> is not really in my source code. I will adjust the post .... ;-)