# Trigger modal if form valid using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I have a problem wherein when a form is submitted, it should trigger a modal when it is valid and if it is not valid, it should  trigger the validation script. I have tried looking for answers in the forum and came across one [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46715241/trigger-modal-if-submitting-valid-form-in-asp-net-mvc-5-application) that resembles mine. But unfortunately, the modal still doesn't pop-up.

What I wanted to happen was when a user clicks the submit button, a validation will run and if all data is valid, it will trigger the modal to pop-up and if invalid, the validation will occur just like [here](http://www.primaryobjects.com/2012/03/21/creating-a-jquery-modal-confirmation-dialog-when-submitting-a-form/).

**MODEL**

```
public class Reg
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter first name")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter MiddleInitial")]
    public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Reg reg)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Reg
<div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-12">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Firstname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Firstname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Firstname) } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Firstname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MiddleInitial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MiddleInitial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.MiddleInitial) } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MiddleInitial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Surname) } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>

<div id="modals" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                Confirm Submit
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="close">×</button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                @Html.Partial("CedulaPartial")
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('form').submit(function () {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        $('#modals').modal('show');
    }
});
```

I also have tried

```
$('#myModal').modal("show");
$('#myModal').dialog('open');
$('#myModal').modal();
$('#myModal').show();
$('#myModal').modal('toggle');
```

but still no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which modal library are you using?

Comment: the default bootstrap of mvc,  Bootstrap v3.0.0

Comment: form has a builtin validate method reportValidity(), may be of help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity

Comment: @leonsegal 1) the OP isn't using the relevant attributes for that 2) It doesn't work at all in any version of IE

Comment: You have not cancelled the default submit action, so you have already left the page (at best you might see a quick flash as the modal is displayed before it leaves. You need to add `return false;` after `$('#modals').modal('show');`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have tried adding return false; after the $('#modals').modal('show'); but still nothing happens

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: @StephenMuecke No errors is showing. After clicking the button, the page loads but the data typed is still in the box like nothing happened.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Is it due to the Post command then called back to  view due to command return View(); ?

Comment: Well, yes. But if you added `return false;` then the  normal submit will be cancelled, and you would never post back to the controller. Put break points in your script and debug it - the script appears to be not executing at all

Comment: On button click you want to trigger modal from java script, then you need to takes button type "button"  instead "Submit"

Comment: @JohnClarenceCastro are there any errors in the network tab?

Comment: @StephenMuecke So it was really posting back. But when I added the return false; event.preventDefault();, the script doesn't seem to execute either. No problem was also popping off when being ran.

Comment: @GhanshyamLakhani I tried changing it to button, now the validation doesn't work

Comment: @leonsegal No errors are showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

After modifying the script, what happens is that the form cannot be clicked. I think the modal is being triggered but no modal is showing. Here is the output:

https://media.giphy.com/media/61Z50T2JEpN1Zrk8hZ/giphy.gif

Until I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093568/bootstrap-modal-not-displaying), I tried removing the `fade` command in class and now the modal is showing. I am currently using Bootstrap v3.0.0 and the fade command has a bug in here. Thanks for your support guys!